# Calling the vue method from inside an event from VueDraggable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drag-and-drop, event-handling, draggable

I am trying to get drag and drop function working in the vue.js app using vue-draggable https://vuejsexamples.com/vuejs-drag-and-drop-library-without-any-dependency/
The library has few events you can listen to and I would like to execute some logic once the item is dropped. However, I am not able to access vue component 'this' along with the data and methods. I've tried to use `this.$dispatch('symDragged', event);` but it is not working for the same reason. 'this' is not a vue instance but rather instance of draggable element.

Here is the code:

```
export default {
components: {
  ICol,
  SymptomsChooser, MultiSelectEditor, TempPressureChooser, BodyPartsEditor, MandatorySymptomsChooser},

data() {
  return {
    // data ommited...
    options: {
      dropzoneSelector: 'ul',
      draggableSelector: 'li',
      excludeOlderBrowsers: true,
      showDropzoneAreas: true,
      multipleDropzonesItemsDraggingEnabled: true,
      onDrop(event) {
        // delete symptom from old basket and add it to new one
        let oldBasket = event.owner.accessKey;
        let newBasket = event.droptarget.accessKey;

        //this is not working
        //this.symDragged(this.draggedSymId, oldBasket, newBasket);
      },
      onDragstart(event) {
        this.draggedSymId = event.items[0].accessKey;
      }
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  symDragged(symId, oldBasketId, newBasketId) {
    console.log("symDragged!");

    let draggedSym = this.getSymById(symId);

    let basketOld = this.getBasketById(oldBasketId);
    this.delSym(basketOld, draggedSym);
    this.addSym({baskedId: newBaskedId, sym: draggedSym});

  }
  //other methods ommited
}
```

}

So, what is the correct way to call the vue component method from callback event? Or maybe I need to create another event so that vue instance could listen to it?

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are facing is that with `this` you are referencing to the returned data object scope and not component scope. The best way to solve this is to make reference to the component instance, so later on you can call anything attached to that instance. You can also take a look at codesandbox example https://codesandbox.io/embed/7kykmmmznq

```
data() {
  const componentInstance = this;

  return {
    onDrop() {
      let oldBasket = event.owner.accessKey;
      let newBasket = event.droptarget.accessKey;
      let draggedItemsAccessKeys = event.items.map(element => element.accessKey);

      componentInstance.symDragged(
        draggedItemsAccessKeys, 
        oldBasket,
        newBasket
      );
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you!